# Dump AWS RDP Server db data

Tags: mysql

I have a AWS Production server with RDP database.

I am accessing db in remote desktop using Putty through this command -

```
mysql -h ----------.rds.amazonaws.com -P (port number) -u (master username) -p (master password)
```

Now I want to dump the server db into a file. In my local MySQL I use to do it through -

```
mysqldump -u (user name) -p (password)
```

But in case of live server I tried this command -

```
mysqldump -h --------.rds.amazonaws.com -P (port number) -u (master username) -p
```

this is not working. How can I dump server RDP db.

Comment: "not working" how? What was the error?

Comment: @underscore_id I used partial command, I saw it afterwards. Complete command is mentioned below. I didn't mentioned db and sql file in the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct command is -

```
mysqldump -h --------.rds.amazonaws.com -P (port number) -u (master username) -p (database name) > (.sql file name).
```

This way we dump the server DB in a file.

Remember to move on .sql file location before running this command in putty. 
Thank you.